# driverjs import in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I am using driverjs in typescript, and

```
import Driver from 'driver.js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DriverjsService {

  private driver: Driver;

  constructor() {
    this.driver = new Driver();
```

this code got 'Cannot use namespace 'Driver' as a type.ts(2709)' this error.

so I did

```
import { Driver, driver } from 'driver.js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DriverjsService {

  public driver: Driver;

  constructor(
  ) {
    this.driver = driver();
  }
```

like that. First of all, there is no error. is this cause a problem?

Written above.
thanks you

Comment: This has nothing to do with ionic. you need to edit the tags and put driverJS instead.